# Technical term for terms never used naturally by native speakers?

Tags: terminology, sociolinguistics, native-language

Apparently, there are some terms that are never used naturally by native speakers. They may only appear under extremely peculiar circumstances (e.g. in some translations of foreign-language texts). A possible example is ***Malvinas Islands***. In view of the fact that apparently no English-speaking countries support Argentina's territorial claims, a native speaker of English may never *naturally* use *Malvinas Islands* instead of *Falkland Islands*. Nonetheless, *Malvinas Islands* is arguably an English term since it has appeared in [Encyclopædia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/place/Falkland-Islands).

Such words and phrases are somehow akin to, but not the same as, [exonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endonym_and_exonym).

Comment: It seems perfectly plausible to me that a native speaker would say "the Falkland Islands, known in Spanish as the Malvinas Islands", even if it's not the official name in any English-speaking country.

Comment: The words a person knows the meaning of, but never uses in one's speech are called the [passive vocabulary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passive%20vocabulary).

Comment: also whilst the Argentinian claims aren't recognised by any English-speaking country, that doesn't mean no native English speakers accept such claims as valid. I suspect there are several such native English speakers who live in Argentina for instance

Comment: This is a **political question** not a linguistics question. As for "terms not used naturally by native speakers", that too, is not a linguistics question. This is not passive vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

This would be *unidiomatic* usage of terms.